# JsonConvert.cs not found

Tags: json.net

Environment:
Visual Studio 2012 Express
.Net Framework 4.5
Windows 7 Professional

While trying to execute this line of code...

```vb
Dim oJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(txtResponse.Text)
```

I get the following error...

> JsonConvert.cs not found

I've properly added a reference to Newtonsoft.Json, so I'm not sure why it would be trying to load a source file...  Any takers???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an exception (handled or not) happening in `JsonConvert` and Visual Studio is trying to open the location of the exception.

Of course, `JsonConvert.cs` is not your code and it doesn't find it.

Turn on "Just My Code" in the [debugging options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.100).aspx) and you won't see this anymore.

1. On the **Tools** menu, choose **Options**.
2. In the Options dialog box, open the **Debugging** node and then choose **General**.
3. Select or clear **Enable Just My Code**.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue only during the debug mode.

**SOLUTION:**

While in Debug mode, this error occurs when you try to **Step Into (F11)** a statement. Just **Step Over (F10)** or **Continue Execution (F5)** on those statements.